# github3.py v1.3.0 AttributeError: iter_repos

Tags: python, github, github3.py

I am trying to iterate over all repositories in a private organization. Here is some example code that does not work on my machine (Windows 10, Python 3.6.5):

```
import github3

session = github3.login(token = "A token that works with other github3.py functions and also has all permissions for testing")
org = session.organization("private organization name")
repos = list(org.iter_repos(type = "all"))
```

When I run this, I get:
    AttributeError: iter_repos
The traceback points to line 5 where I call iter_repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want

```py
   org.repositories(type="all")
```

`iter_repos` is from pre-1.0 github3.py